# Omnipay Integration with new ecommerce platform

Tags: php, joomla, payment-gateway, payment, omnipay

I am developing a new multi vendor ecommerce component for Joomla 3. I am looking for stable open source PHP payment library which will help me to integrate various payment gateways to the component. I have checked Omnipay in Github https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay It looks encouraging. I just installed the library in my local server using composer with all available gateways for testing. I haven't gone through all its functionality or started the integration process. I am getting worried looking at the size of the library. It is around 7.5 MB unpacked. This makes it impossible to be used in my platform. It is just too big. However I feel there are many unnecessary files which I may skip but I am not sure.

Can ansyone advice me the minimum required files which I need to run the library with all available gateways?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of Omnipay.

I don't think the size of the files on disk should be relevant. Composer has an autoloader, so individual PHP files are only included when they are needed, and the extra files won't have any effect on PHP's memory usage.

In terms of distributing the bare minimum, you don't need the tests. Only files in the src directory are required.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not worried about Php memory. My only worry is about the distribution size. I'll exclude the test folders. Can you please also confirm if I can exclude the other libraries folders (eg. symfony, squizlabs, phpunit, mockery, guzzle etc) for distribution? I am planning use standard PHP autoloader so can I also exclude composer?

Comment: That depends, I'm not familiar with Joomla. Guzzle and the dependencies are required, so you either need to bundle them, or if your users have composer they can install them themselves automatically. Phpunit isn't required - try 'composer install --no-dev'